# MYSQL DISTINCT ORDER BY doesn't giving correct order

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, distinct, expressionengine

**Update: Thanks everbody, things are working 100% now with this query:**

```
SELECT e.entry_id
FROM exp_channel_titles AS e
INNER JOIN exp_matrix_data AS m ON m.entry_id = e.entry_id
WHERE e.channel_id = 2
GROUP BY e.entry_id
ORDER BY MIN(m.col_id_2) ASC
```

Here is my code.

Code from .home_laagste_rentes

```
{exp:channel:entries dynamic="no" fixed_order="0{embed:entry_ids}" disable="member_data|pagination|categories"}
<tr class="{switch="odd|even"}">
    <td><a href="#" title="{title}">{title}</a></td>
    <td>{dk:lowest col="rente" decimals="2" dec_point=","}%</td>
    <td>{count}</td>
</tr>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Code from page:

```
<table id="rowspan" cellspacing="0" class="tablesorter">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Krediet aanbieder</th>
            <th>Rente</th>
            <th>Beoordeling</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{embed="embeds/.home_laagste_rentes"
entry_ids="{exp:query sql="
    SELECT DISTINCT (e.entry_id)
    FROM exp_channel_titles AS e
    INNER JOIN exp_matrix_data AS m ON m.entry_id = e.entry_id
    WHERE e.channel_id = 2
    ORDER BY m.col_id_2 ASC
"}|{entry_id}{/exp:query}"}
</tbody>
```

col_id_2 is set as decimal(10,4)

entry_id is set as int

This is filtering duplicates but it's not giving the correct order. It looks like filtering duplicates is done random... See this link for output:
http://postimage.org/image/9vzahuuez/

Comment: that is not the query that creates the table that is linked .. please post the hole query

Comment: Hi Rauschen, just updated with full code..

Comment: @TVoskuilen can you post the `SCHEMA` of tables `exp_channel_titles` and `exp_matrix_data`?

Comment: With this query it is working ok:
    SELECT e.entry_id
    FROM exp_channel_titles AS e
    INNER JOIN exp_matrix_data AS m ON m.entry_id = e.entry_id
    WHERE e.channel_id = 2
    GROUP BY e.entry_id
    ORDER BY MIN(m.col_id_2) ASC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many, possibly different, `m.col_id_2` values, for one `e.entry_id`.

Your query is not even valid ANSI SQL, because `ORDER BY` is evaluated after `DISTINCT`, so `ORDER BY m.col_id_2` should create an error (if your MySQL setting was strict ANSI SQL).

Solution is to state which value should be used for the ordering, using `GROUP BY` instead of `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT e.entry_id
FROM exp_channel_titles AS e
INNER JOIN exp_matrix_data AS m ON m.entry_id = e.entry_id
WHERE e.channel_id = 2
GROUP BY e.entry_id
ORDER BY MAX(m.col_id_2) ASC                  --- or MIN(), or AVG()
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know the `SCHEMA` of your table but you can try this query.

```
SELECT iTable.entry_id
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT e.entry_id, m.col_id_2
    FROM exp_channel_titles AS e INNER JOIN exp_matrix_data AS m 
                ON m.entry_id = e.entry_id
    WHERE e.channel_id = 2) as iTable
ORDER BY iTable.col_id_2 ASC
```